# how to fix GNU assembler (gas) documentation failing to build using mingw64 / msys2?

Tags: mingw-w64, gnu-assembler, msys2, binutils, texinfo

I'm getting errors like this when building binutils-gdb (the gas doc is failing to build). Has anyone seen this before or know how to fix it?

/d/git/binutils-gdb/binutils-gdb-git/gas/doc/as.texi:635: table requires an argument: the formatter for @item

$ makeinfo --version
texi2any (GNU texinfo) 6.3

Comment: You can ask on gdb maillist, also more information should be posted, such as your build environment and how you run command.

Answer (score 0):

This is a CR-LF issue.  Try using dos2unix to convert all your .texi files to Un*x line endings.

```
find <working-directory> -type f -iname "*.texi" -exec dos2unix "{}" \;
```

Where <*working-directory*> is the location of the repository you are trying to build.  You'll need to install the msys/dos2unix package using pacman.

I ran into this problem with the [riscv-gnu-toolchain](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-gnu-toolchain) and it did the trick.